# C# Entity Framework Core - Can't use DbContext.find() with multiple values

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I can't use the Find method of DbContext with multiple values.

I use a SQL Server's database for my project.

```
// The method I call to retrieve an entity
public T FindEntityByUniqueConstraint<T>(params object[] constraints) 
    where T : Entity, IEntity
{
    return this.DbContext.Set<T>().Find(constraints);
}
```

```
// The class of the entity I try to retrieve
[Serializable]
[Table("song")]
public class Song : Entity
{
    [Key, Column("song_id", TypeName = "bigint"), Required]
    [Index("PK_song", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public new int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("song_name", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [Index("IX_song", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string SongName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ArtistId")]
    [Column("artist_id", TypeName = "bigint")]
    [Index("IX_song", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int? ArtistId { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist? Artist { get; set; }

    [Column("dt_saved_dt", TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? DtSavedDt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [ForeignKey("FeatId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Feat>? Feats { get; set; }

    public Song()
    {

    }
}
```

```
// The method's call
Song songTest = entityService.FindEntityByUniqueConstraint<Song>("Fever", 2);
```

You can see I have a primary key (PK_song) on this Song entity (Id property, or song_id in DB), and an index (IX_song) with two column (SongName and ArtistId).

And call the FindEntityByUniqueConstraint's method throw the following exception :

System.ArgumentException : 'Entity type 'Song' is defined with a single key property, but 2 values were passed to the 'Find' method.'

Packages I use :

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "6.0.5",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies": "6.0.5"
```

Comment: What makes you expect that `Find` will also use the index? That's not specified in the documentation.

Comment: @GertArnold When I saw another question with the same subject.

Do you know a good way to do this ?

Comment: It's not about "good" or "bad" way, since there is only one way, and it is using plain LINQ `Where` or `FirstOrDefault` or similar predicate method. `Find` is dedicated for PK, this is by design and cannot be changed. The reason it accepts multiple values is for the case of *composite* (but still *primary*) keys.

Comment: @Marquito I'm curious, which question?

Comment: @IvanStoev As you said, it was necessary to go through the Where clause, it's work and now, I have a generic way to do this, thanks ! ;) And yes, I see it's work when I try with the primary key, now I understand more. :)

Comment: @GertArnold I don't remember exactly, because I see a lot of other forum before I ask my question. But something like me.